# ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.5/lib/' - Go

Tags: go

I am seeing warning as picture showed during running Go unit tests. I found what I have on my mac is version 2.6.

How to change Go to adopt `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.6` instead of using `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.5`?

[image]

---

Tried add following command, but the problem persists
`export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.6/lib/`

Comment: This looks like an environment configuration issue. Does the command work in the OS terminal?

Comment: no. Tried run unit tests from command line `go test ./...`, also seeing the warning. Will remove the 'goland' label

Comment: Then it's probably something that's broken in the OS settings that's causing the issue. I'm not familiar with how Homebrew works, but maybe try to clean the installation of the gsl library first, then make sure there's nothing in the environment configuration pointing to it, and then install the gsl library again. Hope that helps.